# LTO Basics (Build order and how to analyze core dumps)

Tags: gcc, gdb, lto

As the title tells, I do have two basic questions about LTO. First, here are simple demo source files to showcase my basic understanding issues.

`noop.c` to just ship a empty/dead function w/o any operation as:

```
void fnoop(void) {
}
```

`testlib.c` (as shared lib) to loop over fnoop function to demo optimization and to force a segfault as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void fnoop(void);
void force_sigsegv(void) {
   int *p = NULL;
   int a = 0;
   unsigned long i = 0;
   for (i; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
      fnoop();
   }
   a = *p; //segfault
   printf("print a: %d \n",a);
}
```

and here the main application linking against libtestlib as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void force_sigsegv(void);
int main(void) {
   printf("force a sigsegv \n");
   force_sigsegv();
   return 0;
}
```

So, here two ways to build the main application:
(a) separate steps to build testlib shared lib and link application as:

```
mkdir lto
gcc -flto -O3 -c noop.c
gcc -flto -O3 -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libtestlib.so.1 -o lto/libtestlib.so.1 testlib.c noop.o
ln -sf libtestlib.so.1 lto/libtestlib.so
gcc -flto -O3 -o test_lto main.c -L $(pwd)/lto -ltestlib
```

(b) single step to build testlib shared lib and link application as:

```
mkdir lto_single
gcc -flto -O3 -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libtestlib.so.1 -o lto_single/libtestlib.so.1 testlib.c noop.c
ln -sf libtestlib.so.1 lto_single/libtestlib.so
gcc -flto -O3 -o test_lto_single main.c -L $(pwd)/lto_single -ltestlib
```

With (a) the for-loop gets optimized out as:

```
00000000000011b0 <force_sigsegv>:                                                                                                                                   11b0:       8b 04 25 00 00 00 00    mov    0x0,%eax
11b7:       0f 0b                   ud2
11b9:       0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

and with (b) the for-loop remains as:

```
00000000000011c0 <force_sigsegv>:                                                                                                                                   11c0:       53                      push   %rbx
11c1:       bb 00 ca 9a 3b          mov    $0x3b9aca00,%ebx
11c6:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
11cd:       00 00 00
11d0:       e8 4b fe ff ff          callq  1020 <fnoop@plt>
11d5:       48 83 eb 01             sub    $0x1,%rbx
11d9:       75 f5                   jne    11d0 <force_sigsegv+0x10>
11db:       8b 04 25 00 00 00 00    mov    0x0,%eax
11e2:       0f 0b                   ud2
11e4:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
11eb:       00 00 00
11ee:       66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

***Question 1*: why is the for-loop not optimized out in case of (b)?**

Next: analyzing core dumps generated by the the two applications from above.
Let's say we have the test_lto, which uses optimized testlib share lib from (a), in our production system and it forces the core dump and the user sends it to me. I will start to analyze by:
(1) load it into gdb to find the crash address, eg:

```
Core was generated by `./test_lto'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007fba3aa211b0 in ?? ()
```

(2) find object which the adress belongs to by using `readelf -n corefile`, eg:

```
0x00007fba3aa20000  0x00007fba3aa21000  0x0000000000000000
/volume/LTO/lto/libtestlib.so.1
0x00007fba3aa21000  0x00007fba3aa22000  0x0000000000000001
/volume/LTO/lto/libtestlib.so.1
```

(3) find text segment offset of lto version of testlib using `readelf -t libtestlib.so.1`, eg:

```
  [ 8] .text
PROGBITS         0000000000001040  0000000000001040  0
```

and finally add this information to gdb as:

```
(gdb) core lto/core
[New LWP 1599]
Core was generated by `./test_lto'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007fba3aa211b0 in ?? ()
(gdb) add-symbol-file lto/libtestlib.so.1 0x00007fba3aa20000+0x1040
add symbol table from file "lto/libtestlib.so.1" at
.text_addr = 0x7fba3aa21040
(y or n) y
Reading symbols from lto/libtestlib.so.1...
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fba3aa211b0 in force_sigsegv ()
```

So, not able to gather (helpful) crash detail. Even when using the lto_single version of testlib from (b) does not give more detail. However, building the same objects w/o `-flto` but with `-g` and loading into gdb using same address `0x00007fba3aa20000+0x1040` gives:

```
Reading symbols from nlto/libtestlib.so.1...
(gdb) bt
#0  force_sigsegv () at testlib.c:13
```

But(!) checking line#13 points to `fnoop()` call inside the for-loop. So the trace is not correct leading to wrong information.

***Question 2*: How to analyze core dumps generated by optimized binaries (-flto)?**

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!
With GCC-6 there was the limitation (see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.5.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options)):

> Link-time optimization does not work well with generation of debugging information. Combining -flto with -g is currently experimental and expected to produce unexpected results.

With GCC-10 (checked also w/ GCC-9) this limitation was removed (see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.4.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options)).

So when mixing `-flto` and `-g` the issue about wrong core dump trace is solved (tested w/ GCC-9/10). Just do it as usual, ship the stripped version and keep the debug version for post-mortem.

Answer (score 0):

However, Question 1 remains.

Also from GCC-9 docs:

> Another (simpler) way to enable link-time optimization is:
> `gcc -o myprog -flto -O2 foo.c bar.c`

I am wondering why this does not produces the same disassembly as (even the docs state it should):

```
gcc -c -O2 -flto foo.c
gcc -c -O2 -flto bar.c
gcc -o myprog -flto -O2 foo.o bar.o
```

So if anyone can help here, please do so :-)

Comment: I checked, and this is related to -fPIC. If I build the shared lib w/o -fPIC as: `gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libtestlib.so.1 -o libtestlib.so.1 -flto -g -O3 testlib.c noop.c` then the for-loop is optimized out.